# Decimal support Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, decimal

Trying to use decimal128 datatype in my nodejs application.

> mongo version "3.4.2",
>
> os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.7.0"
>
> nodejs version 6.11.2
>
> mongoose version 4.11.13
>
> mongoose using native mongodb driver version 2.2.31

Mongodb config:

```
storage:
    engine: wiredTiger
    dbPath: "/Users/backend/Desktop/mongo/data"
```

What am i doing? 
I've got mongoose subdocument schema

```
const Premises = mongoose.Schema({
  floor           : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128, required: true },
  deleted         : { type: Boolean, default: false },
  created_at      : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at      : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

This schema is a subdocument of document with schema below:

```
...
premises            : [  Premises ],
...
```

To add new subdocuments im using **update** method:

```
var queryFilter = {
    'deleted'           : false,
    'buildings._id'     : params.building_id
  };

var premise = {
    '_id':                  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    'floor': params['floor']
  };


Block.update(queryFilter, { '$addToSet': { 'buildings.$.premises': premise } }, { safe: true }, function (error, result) {

        result['_id'] = premise['_id'];

        callback(error, result || null);
        return;

      });
```

Also i used code below:

```
var queryFilter = {
    'deleted'           : false,
    'buildings._id'     : params.building_id
  };

  var premise = {
    '_id':                  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    'floor': mongoose.Types.Decimal128.fromString(params['floor'])
  };

  Block.update(queryFilter, { '$addToSet': { 'buildings.$.premises': premise } }, { safe: true }, function (error, result) {

    result['_id'] = premise['_id'];

    callback(error, result || null);
    return;

  });
```

But get the same error in both situations:

> {"errors":{"name":"MongoError","message":"$numberDecimal is not valid
>   for
>   storage.","driver":true,"index":0,"code":52,"errmsg":"$numberDecimal
>   is not valid for
>   storage."},"data":{"ok":0,"n":0,"nModified":0,"_id":"59ce4e8cecba947a9a342f37"}}

I dont wanna use some workaround like

> mongoose-double

to support negative numbers in my collections.
Much thanx for ur answers and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue "$numberDecimal is not valid for storage" when I tried to add subdocument into array.
I tend to think this happens because of

```
Decimal128.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return { "$numberDecimal": this.toString() };
}
```

from http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/node_modules_bson_lib_bson_decimal128.js.html
Maybe that is not the best solution but workaround below helped me:

```
mongoose.Types.Decimal128.prototype.toJSON = mongoose.Types.Decimal128.prototype.toString;
```

For adding item to an existing array I used:

```
  entity.subentities.addToSet(subentity);  
  const updatedEntity = await entity.save();
```